# $timeout inside angular forEach not working

Tags: angularjs, loops, foreach, timeout

My $timeout is set to run on each request inside the forEach loop, however it doesn't timeout the getDistance function so that the Directions service request limit per second is not reached.

```
        let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        properties.forEach((property) => {
                $timeout(getDistance(property), 1000)
        });

        function getDistance(property) {
            let propertyLocation = {lat: property.geoLocation.lat, lng: property.geoLocation.lon};
            directionsService.route({
                origin: center,
                destination: propertyLocation,
                travelMode: 'TRANSIT'
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    console.log(response, status);
                    property.distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
                } else {
                    property.distance = 'No distance';
                }
            });
        }
```

Any help?

Comment: try this `properties.forEach((property) => {
                $timeout(() => { getDistance(property) }, 1000)
        });`, don't directly call function when passing it as reference in `$timeout`

Comment: hello, that works for delaying the initial call, I am looking to delay each call for every property. Is this how to do it?

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: This sets a timeout on executing the loop, however, I would like to set a timeout on each iteration in the loop rather than just the start.

Comment: you might need to write recursive function